# LongListSelector Data Virtualization

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Does `LongListSelector` support Data Virtualization? I read on several Blogs that it does, but can't get it to work.

Here is what I tried: I provided a `IList` implementation as `ItemsSource` to the List. The problem is that the List calls `GetEnumerator()` instead of `this[int index]` to get a list item.

So my question: How do I implement data virtualization for `LongListSelector`?

Comment: Do you wish to data virtualize on groups, or on all the items?

Comment: on the groups. the groups contain the items, so the `LongListSelector` should read as many groups as it needs, until it has enough groups and items.

Comment: Yes, but you should remember that the LongListSelector uses a nested collection for data display. So you would most likely have to virtualize both the inner and the outer collections.

Comment: @claus: thanks for your quick answer. could you provide an example how this would work? In my program each group contains a list of items. is this the right data structure for virtualization?

Comment: Nope. Because as you said, the LongListSelector is still based around GetEnumerator even for when rendering IList types. Most likely the control would need to be rewritten to support the purpose. While blogs might say it support it, none of them says how, so I'm not inclined to believe them. The LongListSelector's default is to render all items. And for instance, 100.000 items renders instantly, so I don't see the concern that requires data virtualization in the first place.

Comment: @Claus: 100.00 items render instantly? on your phone or on the emulator ;)  anyway, in most cases the rendering is not the costly operation, as there is also UI virtualization that will only render what is necessary. But getting the 100.00 items from a file or database is what takes its time. In conclusion, I think you are right, `LongListSelector` likely is not "data virtualizable". Please make your last comment an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, the LongListSelector is still based around GetEnumerator even for when rendering IList types. Most likely the control would need to be rewritten to support the purpose. While blogs might say it support it, none of them says how, so I'm not inclined to believe them. The LongListSelector's default is to render all items.

As for the loading of the data, it can be done progressive using a ObservableCollection. I got a [example project](https://github.com/Windcape/Diverse/tree/master/LongListSample) that shows how to use a ObservableCollection in combination with the LongListSelector.

Basically this could allow you to progressively add more groups and/or, more data to the groups, and the UI should update accordingly.

Comment: Example project link, access denied.

Comment: It's on GitHub now. Link fixed.

Comment: Um, now the example project is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the LongListSelector source code, it is NOT possible to virtualize the backing storage. The LongListSelector loads each item from the group list through a foreach loop.