# Fill listbox with subitems async, makes listbox freeze

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous

Im trying to fill a list box with a projectlist which contains a list of configurations.

So what I'm trying to do is first fill the listbox with my projectlist and all subitems. This is all going well. But for each configuration I need to do a call to a rest service to get a status. So I do not whant to make all theese requests at once (first bind projects and configurations and then for each configuration fetch status and have the configuration status property updated async. But when I start to load all configurations (can be up to aprox 200) the listbox freezes.

**RED: After some thinking it should be better to load status of each listitem (subitem) when it becoms visible for the user, however I can't find any good events for this. Any sugestions on how to handle this?**

Here is my solution:

```
MainViewModel
```

```cs
//Fired on pageLoad
_projectRepository.FindBy(_serverCityConfiguration, BuildListBoxGroups);


    private void BuildListBoxGroups(IEnumerable<Project> projects)
    {
        var projectGroups = new List<ListBoxGroup<BuildConfigurationModel>>();

        foreach (Project project in projects)
        {
            var buildConfigurations = project.BuildConfigurations.Select(buildConfiguration 
                => new BuildConfigurationModel(buildConfiguration.Id, buildConfiguration.Name, new List<BuildModel>())).ToList();
            projectGroups.Add(new ListBoxGroup<BuildConfigurationModel>(
                new ProjectModel(project.Id, project.Name), buildConfigurations));
        }
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                                  Projects = projectGroups.ToObservableCollection());

        //It's here my problem starts, where my listbox freezes
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FireBuildsFetching, projects);

    }

    private void FireBuildsFetching(object stuff)
    {
        var projects = stuff as IEnumerable<Project>;
        foreach (var project in projects)
        {
            foreach (var buildConfiguration in project.BuildConfigurations)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RetrieveBuils, buildConfiguration);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RetrieveBuils(object buildConfiguration)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("RetrieveBuils");
        var localBuildConfig = buildConfiguration as BuildConfiguration;

        //Here is some logic to find correct buildconfiguration to add status to
        ...
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                          buildConfigurationModel.AddBuilds(buildModels));                                                                                    

     }
```

When all calls to rest service is done, the listbox is updated with all status at once.

Someone having any good solutions to my problem?

Comment: Check out the async ctp 3, the examples might give you some ideas.

Comment: Well the CTP 3 looks nice but it wouldn't help me!? CTP just wraps all callbacks and stuff, still something wrong in my code.

Comment: There is an example using tasks to populate a ListBox in the background, I thought that may help.

Comment: Do you have a link? I can't find any good examples.

Comment: Do you have the async ctp? If you don't want to install it I can send you the docs and samples.

Comment: No thats fine, I have it and will look at it once more. However, the samples does not give me an example of how to load items when they get visible on screen (or when theya are nerly visible). Any ideas?

Comment: look at this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768725/longlistselector-data-virtualization

Comment: I'm still stuck with my problem. I have updated so I now use CTP 3 (much cleaner code :)).

But, the long list selector does not let me be able to load data when it's becoming visible or needed by the UI. 
The ListBox does but there I can't categorize my results.

Have looked at Jumplist but it fails with 7.1.

Comment: I think that will be difficult with a longlist selector but possible with a regular listbox.  I will try to make an example with a listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a wait (thread.Sleep) of 50ms to your background loop. Seems to me your listbox is continuously updated by the background threat. Marshalling from threads + updating UI claims takes resources. Optimizing your code by minimizing the number of roundtrips, and batch update data (per 10 or 20 items) can help. Hope this helps.