# How to Check if ListBox Bound to ObservableCollection is Virtualized

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am working on trying to make my application as efficient as possible, and I have read about ListBox automatically virtualizing its data in Windows Phone 8. I have implemented an `ItemContainerStyle` style that I use within my ListBox, and I am not sure if this effects virtualization of items bound to the ListBox. My items are images, and they are loaded from IsolatedStorage into an ObservableCollection when MainPage is initialized. Is this solution ok? If not, any better recommendations?

The Style

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property ="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>                              
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="brd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>                                
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="brd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Viewbox MaxHeight="128" MaxWidth="128" >
                                <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="12" Width="115"/>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Border>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="imgListContextMenu" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">                                    
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="edit" Click="editContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="favorite" Click="favoriteContextMenuItem_Click"/>                                    
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="delete" Click="deleteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

The ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="Recent" Margin="8"
                     SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures;
    }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public static PictureRepository PictureList
    {
        get
        {
            return PictureRepository.Instance;
        }
    }
```

PictureRepository.cs

```
#region Constants

    public const string IsolatedStoragePath = "Pictures";

    #endregion

    #region Fields

    private readonly ObservableCollection<Picture> _pictures = new ObservableCollection<Picture>();

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures
    {
        //get { return _pictures; }
        get;
        private set;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Singleton Pattern

    private PictureRepository()
    {
        LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage();
    }

    public static readonly PictureRepository Instance = new PictureRepository();

    #endregion

    /// <summary>        
    /// Saves to local storage
    /// This method gets two parameters: the captured picture instance and the name of the pictures folder in the isolated storage
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="capturedPicture"></param>
    /// <param name="directory"></param>
    public void SaveToLocalStorage(CapturedPicture capturedPicture, string directory)
    {
        //call IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to get an isolated storage file
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists.
        isoFile.EnsureDirectory(directory);

        //Combine the pictures folder and captured picture file name and use this path to create a new file 
        string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, capturedPicture.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = isoFile.CreateFile(filePath))
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
            {
                capturedPicture.Serialize(writer);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To load all saved pictures and add them to the pictures list page
    /// </summary>
    public CapturedPicture LoadFromLocalStorage(string fileName, string directory)
    {
        //To open the file, add a call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //Combine the directory and file name
        string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
        //use the path to open the picture file from the isolated storage by using the IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile method
        using (var fileStream = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            //create a BinaryReader instance for deserializing the CapturedPicture instance
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
            {
                var capturedPicture = new CapturedPicture();
                //create a new instance of the type CapturedPicture called CapturedPicture.Deserialize to deserialize the captured picture and return it
                capturedPicture.Deserialize(reader);
                return capturedPicture;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To load all the pictures at start time
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage()
    {
        //add call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to open an isolated storage file
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists
        isoFile.EnsureDirectory(IsolatedStoragePath);

        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames using the pictures directory and *.jpg as a filter to get all saved pictures
        var pictureFiles = isoFile.GetFileNames(Path.Combine(IsolatedStoragePath, "*.jpg"));

        var pictures = new List<Picture>();

        //Iterate through all the picture files in the list and load each using the LoadFromLocalStorage you created earlier
        foreach (var pictureFile in pictureFiles)
        {
            var picture = LoadFromLocalStorage(pictureFile, IsolatedStoragePath);
            //_pictures.Add(picture);
            pictures.Add(picture);
        }

        Pictures = new ObservableCollection<Picture>(pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken));
    }
```

EDIT** New Implementation using LongListSelector?
I changed my ListBox in my view to a `LongListSelector` and set the `LayoutMode="Grid"` which seems to mimic a WrapPanel. I'm hoping the virtualization that I need will exist. Any suggestions or advice?

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Height="108" Width="108" Margin="6,6" Orientation="Horizontal">               
            <Viewbox Width="108" Height="108">
                <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="6,6" Width="108"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>        
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Recent" Margin="8" 
                                    SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" 
                                    toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="108,108"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
```

Note that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are NOT virtualizing. When you set the ItemsPanel of the ListBox, you remove the ability to virtualize.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Recent" Margin="8"
                 SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel> <!-- This is removing virtualization-->
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

You can test this by removing the ItemsPanel customization and adding 1000 items. Scroll the listbox and look at the load time of the control. Add the customization back in and you'll notice decreased performance and increased load time.

That said, you may want to see how some of the [WPF virtualizing wrap panels](http://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/) work on WP8. I tried them in a WPF project I did previously and didn't have as much luck as I would have liked, but your results may vary.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I don't see much along the way of a good virtualized wrappanel implementation either. I changed my `ListBox` to a `LongListSelector`, and used `LayoutMode="Grid"` to collect my images which mimic a WrapPanel. I edited my solution above to show this. I referenced http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093 for good measure. I'm hoping this method will keep the virtualization? From also referencing http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth it seems I should be ok.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't look like `LongListSelector` supports virtualization, at least according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768725/longlistselector-data-virtualization. I'd be inclined to forego efforts to improve your application in this area unless it's a real trouble spot. The amount of work you'd need to do to get a `WrapPanel` look with virtualization is above and beyond what most would consider worth it.

Comment: Yes I've ran accross that link as well. You're right, I'll probably stick with the `LongListSelector` however for the mean time in case extended functionality or updating is needed later. My app could potentially load hundreds of images, maybe rendering them on the view within a viewbox would aid some. I have seen other implementations of only loading a few pages of data at a time, I may have to implement one of those solutions as well. I will mark your answer as correct, I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: You could also use lower res images (thumbnails) to reduce the memory load. Depends on your needs of course.