# How to show big data without hitting memory limit?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to show a very long list of comments, which contains text, image, username, etc, in a `LongListSelector` using binding.

Can get all comments by one request only. when I show those comments, app hits memory limit and exits.

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

What can I do in this scenario? thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/01/24/windows-phone-8-longlistselector-memory-leak/

Comment: Use the force Luke... I mean search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768725/longlistselector-data-virtualization

Comment: @crea7or what you are referring to is not related to my question (they are wrong though! `LongListSelector` loads what it needs, to proof see how `ItemRealized` event works). I can't have those all items in memory, i.e an ObservableCollection in ViewModel, I want to know what else can I do.

Comment: @user3293835 [UI virtualization should not be confused with data virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `ItemRealized` related to UI virtualization. And in your case you need data virtualization (in addition to built-in UI virtualization), that is what link from crea7or demonstrates, data virtualization with LLS. Unfortunately, link to download project example there is dead :(